# What's the difference between using <%def%> and <%include%> in mako?

Tags: mako

They both let you stick some mako-rendered content into another one.  Both let you pass in arguments.

Is there a performance difference between the two?  A philosophical one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Def is for defining functions in the template, while include executes another file.

The mako documentation summarizes thus:

> Calling a `<%def>` from another template is something like using an
>   `<%include>` – except you are calling a specific function within the
>   template, not the whole template.

(from http://docs.makotemplates.org/en/latest/defs.html)

Of course, `<%include>` involves another file, you can call a `<%def>` from the same file it is defined in.

Comment: Right, I get that, but is the advantage just that include requires you to write lots of small .mak files while def lets you write one larger one?  Is it just a difference in what you think clean code looks like?

Comment: Just using `<%include>` requires you to write lots of small mako files.  But if your code is large enough, you don't want to use only `<%def>` either.  You want to use `<%def>` for functions and split your functions into appropriate modules that are `<%include>`d, just like you would do (hopefully) with collections in other languages like C, Javascript, Python, ASP, etc.